# Standard Stream Printing Unrelated Characters

Tags: c++, string, file, stream

I was coding something and my code didn't work correctly in some situations, so I decided to write some output to file for debugging. The program just concatenates some characters from a string (and it didn't get out of bounds) and printed them to the file. It has no thing as error reporting or something, and the input string is just a bunch of random characters. But, i get some junk in the output, such as:

```
f::xsgetn error reading the file
sgetn error reading the file
ilebuf::xsgetn error reading the file
```

(I removed program's output and this is just the extra stuff.)

As far as I know, if there are any errors, an exception must be thrown. What happens and how can I fix it?

The same thing happens when I print the output using standard output. All used libraries are standard libraries (eg. iostream, fstream, etc.)

PS: For some reasons, I can't publish all the code. Here is the part that creates the output and passes it to stream: (tri is and string, and is defined previously. Center is an integer and is inside the bounds of the string. fout is a previously defined file stream.)

```
string op = "" + tri[center];
fout << center << "<>" << op << endl;
```

Comment: Your code has a bug.  Nobody can see it from here.

Comment: Do you expect us know magically what you did wrong without seeing what you actually did? For all we know you didn't allocate enough memory on line 12.

Comment: @KerrekSB: What's wrong with you? It's perfectly obvious the bug is on line 42!

Comment: @JerryCoffin: That's lame: you commented after the edit, so you were already aware of "some reasons" for not seeing the code. Of course now line 42 is far more likely.

Comment: @KerrekSB: But how could you fail to realize that 42 is *always* the answer?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: May be because 42 is the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe and everything. If you don't believe me, google it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tri` is a `string`, `tri[center]` is a `char`.
The type of `""` is `const char[]`, which can't be added to a `char`.
Instead it is implicitly converted to `const char*`, which *can* be added to a `char`.

Unfortunately for you, the result of that is that the integer value of `tri[center]`is added to that pointer *as an offset*, not as a string concatenation, and the particular area of memory that the result refers to doesn't contain what you're looking for but instead contains other static strings like e.g. "error reading the file".

To fix it, use

string op = string("") + tri[center];

instead.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem in another program, where I had written:

```
str += blablabla + "#";
```

and I saw some unrelated characters being printed. I fixed it this way:

```
str = str + blablabla + "#";
```

and it worked!

There is some problem with the `+=` operator for `string`.